# Isn't Nasheed also haraam as acapella is haraam & they both share the same attributes?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, music

People advise to listen to nasheed to move away from musical instruments and haraam music. But many scholars also say Acapella even with decent and appropriate lyrics is haraam too. But if you look closely, nasheeds are the same as acapellas. So, wouldn't nasheeds be haraam too?

Comment: A very good point. Thank you for bringing this up. In many modern nasheeds (vocals only that is) has acapella or beatboxing, where people use their voice to mimic the sound of music. And many scholars even suggest it to be haram, so it seems like vocals only nasheeds appear to be a problem too. So the question is, what part of "music" are we saying is haram. Is it the rhythm/sound of musical instrument, is it the instrument alone or is it the lyrics? I would really love to see people comment on this question, for those who say music is haram. Again thx for bringing this up!